# Spring Boot Stormpath Database

Tags: stormpath

I have just come accross stormpath and I would like to test it with Spring Boot. I am developing a web application with Spring MVC. Do I need a database for storing all the user data? where are the users stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, no. You don't need a database to store the user data. It's stored at Stormpath and you interact with your user data via the Stormpath API.

The Spring Boot integration makes it very easy to work with Stormpath.

In the [Java SDK project](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java), there's a [tutorial](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/tutorials) section that starts you with the most basic Spring Boot app and walks you through to integrating with Stormpath using the full breadth of Spring Security roles and permissions constructs.

There's lots of good information in the docs [here](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/) as well.

Full disclosure: I work for Stormpath.

Best,

Micah